# ImageButton Not getting the GridView cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, imagebutton, detailsview

The code was working before and all i did was add a new textbox in the header template of the gridview.

So What is my code doing:

i have an image button on my gridview view when clicked i take the value of of the current row of the gridview and the value of cell 3 and set it equal to my textbox. Then based on that value i am making two details view visible using a modal popup extender, one detail view renders correctly but will not function unless it gets the value from textbox10.text as a parameter, another details view will not even show the details because the select query takes the textbox10.text as a parameter.

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
}
else
{
ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)sender;
GridViewRow GridView1 = (GridViewRow)imgbtn.NamingContainer;
string workordernum = GridView1.Cells[3].Text;

TextBox10.Text = workordernum;

//TextBox10.Text = "1";

ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
DetailsView2.Visible = true;
ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
DetailsView1.Visible = true;
}
}
```

when i put the above code in debug mode:
[image]

after debug completed:
[image]

When i set the textbox10.text = 1 and ran the application:

[image]

complete application with value 1:

[image]

.aspx code of the details view:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="pnl2" PopupControlID="pnl2" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  DropShadow="False" X="30" Y="300" ValidateRequestMode="Inherit"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />

<asp:Panel ID="pnl2" runat="server" Width="881px" Height="175px" CssClass="pnl2BackGround" >
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" BackColor="#593B03"  Height="175px" Width="881px" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" PostBack = "False" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="WorkOrderNum" >
<Fields>
<asp:BoundField DataField="WorkOrderNum" HeaderText="WorkOrderNum" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="WorkOrderNum" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Requestor" HeaderText="Requestor" SortExpression="Requestor" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd-M-yyyy}" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="CompletionDate" HeaderText="CompletionDate" SortExpression="CompletionDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd-M-yyyy}" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="MachineDescription" HeaderText="MachineDescription" SortExpression="MachineDescription" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="MachineLocation" HeaderText="MachineLocation" SortExpression="MachineLocation" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Type_of_Work_Order" HeaderText="Type_of_Work_Order" SortExpression="Type_of_Work_Order" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Work_Required" HeaderText="Work_Required" SortExpression="Work_Required" />
</Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WorkOrderConnectionString6 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [WorkOrderNum], [Requestor], [Date], [Department], [CompletionDate], [MachineDescription], [MachineLocation], [Type of Work Order] AS Type_of_Work_Order, [Work Required] AS Work_Required FROM [Master] WHERE ([WorkOrderNum] = @WorkOrderNum)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox10" Name="WorkOrderNum" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The Code i am using for the searching of the gridview from the header template:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
ViewState["Filter"] = "All";
DetailsView1.Visible = false;
TextBox10.Visible = false;
DetailsView2.Visible = false;
DetailsView3.Visible = false;
ReportViewer1.Visible = false;
BindGrid();

}

}

private void BindGrid()
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
String WorkOrderConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
.ConnectionStrings["WorkOrderConnectionString3"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WorkOrderConnectionString);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spx_GetWorkOrderNum");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Filter", ViewState["Filter"].ToString());
cmd.Connection = con;
sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
sda.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
TextBox TextBox92 = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("WorkOrderNum");


}
protected void TextBox92_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
TextBox TextBox92 = (TextBox)sender;
ViewState["Filter"] = TextBox92.Text;
this.BindGrid();
}
```

**I am suspecting that post back might be the issue, some where in the code it is doing an unnessary post back so when i click the imagebutton it is not getting the value**

Please help me find the error in my code as the debugger is not helping me and plus this was a working code before :(

**WHY THE TEXTBOX VALUE = "" INSTEAD OF THE GRIDVIEW CELL VALUE??????**
Thanks

Comment: In which way is it not working now?

Comment: @Andrei it is setting the textbox values to "" im not sure if there is a postback causing this ? or if textbox10 is not receiving the value, etc the application works when i physically enter in a textbox10 value.

Comment: @Andrei do me a favor and dont vote a Question down if you dont give an answer :)

Comment: Never did. If you want a guess why was this downvoted, i'd say because of the screenshots that are next to unreadable. But again, wasn't me who pressed -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Gridview is a Control and TextBox is also an Control within the Gridview control we nee to do this:

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)

  {
   ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)sender;
   GridViewRow GridView1Row = (GridViewRow)imgbtn.NamingContainer;
   Label FLabel = GridView1Row.Cells[2].Controls[0].FindControl("Label1") as Label;
                string workordernum = FLabel.Text;// GridView1Row.Cells[3].Text;

                TextBox10.Text = workordernum;

                    ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
                    DetailsView2.Visible = true;
                    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
                    DetailsView1.Visible = true;



        }
```